# how to show MKAnnotation callout view when scrollview to page or change MKAnnotation pin picture when scroll to page

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, mkannotation

I want to show MKannotation callout view when scrollview go to page or change MKAnnotation pin picture when scroll to page for show the place in scroll picture place can I do this in function

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
```

Comment: yes, you can do it in above function.

Comment: you can show me for example I'll use and test it.